# Desabilitar checkbox desmarcado javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso desabilitar todos os checkbox que não estão selecionados/marcados.
Tentei com o seguinte código:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
   if($(this).prop("checked", false)){
      $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', false).prop("disabled", true);   
   }
});
```

Mas ta errado pq não esta funcionando.

To precisando de uma força pra colocar isso pra funcionar.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
  if (!this.checked) this.disabled = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

Ou numa só linha:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
```

O `.change()` irá correr só quando o valor mudar, e só naquele que mudar.

Comment: Valeu @Sergio. Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @BrunoOliveira ótimo!